# From column to matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have few addresses in a single column. Need to move it to rows as below:

```
name1
street1
city1
state1
phone1
email1
name2
street2
city2  
state2
phone2
email2

NAME   ADDRESS  PHONE  EMAIL
name1  address1 phone1 email1
name2  address2 phone2 email2
```

Please help me to get the right formula.

Comment: You changed street, city, state to address. Is this one cell? What have you tried doing already? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Use a good text editor that supports regular expressions (check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297569/free-windows-gui-text-editor-supporting-regular-expressions-for-programmers)) instead of excel. You would probably want to replace a line break (either \r or \n or both depending on your text file encoding) with a tab (which is \t in regex). This will turn a list of values into a row. If your values end in numbers as they do in your example, then you could even use these to indicate the start of the next row, but that would be tricky.

You may have to tinker a little to get it exactly right, but based on your question, this will give you close to what you want. If you simply have a list of values with no computer-readable means of distinguishing between say, a city and a state, then no regular expression will help you to convert it to a true matrix, and you'll have to manually delimit the values, perhaps by finding an email address (there are plenty of regular expressions that'll do that) and suffix it with some unique identifier that you can then use to identify the end of a row (based on the order of the values in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in cell **A1** , in **B1** enter:

=INDEX($A:$A,(6*ROW()-5)+(COLUMN()-2),1)

Then copy **B1** to **C1** thru **G1**

Then copy **C1** thru **G1** down as far as you need.

For example:

[image: demo]